# Any way to disable default escaping in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I got a UNIX-Win mixed file which I need to barely transform. I would like to change as minimum as possible, but using SAXON xslt, it escapes a lot of chars like `/` -> `&#47;` and some CR LFs.

Is there anyway to tell the transform to not touch ANYTHING unless the match and specification is done??

Thanks!!

Comment: What is a "UNIX-Win mixed file"? And what are your settings for the `<xsl:output>` element of your stylesheet? And which version of Saxon?

Comment: I guess chracters mixed from both according to WinMerge whereas the SAXON output is described as pure UNIX (homogenious CRLF I guess). SAXOIN is the last HE downloaded yesterday, using command line. XML:output is in XML no first line, no indent, I just want to trho out the original doc but the changes.

Comment: A file, no matter where it originated, is supposed to have an [encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). What is the encoding of your source XML file, and what is the output encoding (if any) specified in the stylesheet?

Comment: Does not matter, as all I want is the parser respects the encoding. And I think it's more than encoding as it also replaces special chars

Comment: "*Does not matter*" Okay, then.

Comment: I find it hard to imagine any circumstances in which Saxon will output '/' as &#47;. Please supply more details of the input and the way you are running it.

Comment: java -jar saxon9he.jar -s:file.ktr -xsl:Transformation.xslt -o:file.ktr.update, file is a unix designed Kettle transformation, xslt is an identity transform with a simple template match and a heading of <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the attribute- disable-output-escaping

```
<xsl:value-of select="expression" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Comment: Thanks Vinit, but it is the whole document that is "fixed" by the inner parser

Answer (score 1):

XSLT doesn't operate on a sequence of characters, but on the tree defined by the XPath data model.  There are some properties of the input that the XSLT processor cannot preserve, because it does not see them in the first place.  This includes the amount of whitespace between attribute-value specifications in start-tags, the difference between literal characters and numeric character references, and the line-boundary sequences (CRLF, LF, or CR) in the input.

If the reason you want to change as little as possible is that you have downstream processes which only kind of, sort of, understand XML, then some XML users will tell you that what you should do is get rid of that broken software and use XML-aware software instead.

If the reason you want to change it as little as possible is that it's beautifully formatted and you don't want it mucked up, you may be able to reproduce your beautiful formatting with XSLT.  Or not.

If you really really need to preserve the distinction between Unix LF sequences and Windows CRLF sequences, you may want to consider some tool that takes a lower-level view of things.  Perhaps you can write your transformation in sed.  Perhaps you can write a simple transformation in sed that will turn the data into a form that you can read, modify, and rewrite with XSLT without information loss (and then another sed transform to read the XSLT output and put it back into the Win/Unix mix format).  Some people would prefer to use Perl instead of sed.  Some would do it all in Elisp.

Comment: The reason is that I am modifying by hand a third app propetary file that disposes the content in XML, and additionally I am modifying it from another platform. So I would like to change the least possible and just the necessary indicated xslt matches. And yes, I am indeed looking for sed :)